# What classifier should I use to find out expected subsequent purchased category for each user based on the month he is buying?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-science

Which classifier in Machine Learning should I use to predict the expected subsequent purchased category based on the month he is purchasing?
Given a dataset consisting of columns 
`uuid date price product_id category`
I am guessing the Naive Bayes algorithm, any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In ML, you cann't rely on single model, try every model which you can try out and pick which gives best result. I generally start with simple model such as **Ridge**, **Logistic regression**, **Elastic net**, **SVM** etc. which still work very good. then i look into tree based and gradient boosting models.

If you have product/users features then use can try **KNN** model on those features, which find the k-similar neighbours.

Also, if you would like to look in the **recommendation system**, [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj8sZ_kl7LhAhVDLY8KHYMlB5MQFjALegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRecommender_system&usg=AOvVaw2mjZ93DtoBXPqITfA3MrV2) may be helpful. In product recommendation, these models works pretty good.